# The [panel] tag is vague

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panel) - 31 questions

Most are meaning [electrical-panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-panel) but there's a couple talking about wood paneling and one about fence panels. We should probably retag the non-electrical ones and synonym.

Comment: [tag:panel] doesn't have a wiki either, and it probably should when/if this change is done.

Comment: I'm all for [tag:panel] becoming an alias for electrical-panel to deal with the 90%, but it'd be nice to make a `paneling` or `wall-covering` tag to cover the rest.

Comment: @chicks That would be the idea. Clean the tag up (make new tags as needed) and then synonym

Comment: I cleaned up all the existing `panel` questions that deal with electrical matters to use `electrical-panel` instead

Comment: I retagged the remaining questions and added [tag:paneling], along with an excerpt (pending approval)